# How durable are IElementHandle objects?

Tags: playwright

Rather impressive so far, just starting with Playwright, really nice, really impressed so far!

I'm curious about the durability/life cycle for elements we get back from QuerySelector*() methods.  Given most web libraries/frameworks like Angular and React may remove and graft in a new UI element...   Should we code in such a way to assume the elements are more transient and should always perform a QuerySelectorAsync() prior to using, given my element was previously fetched?  So far it seems values is fetched real time, i.e get the control, check value, change value, getting the value now will get the current/updated value.

More interested what is expected behavior after the may DOM updated by our respective UI Libs/Frameworks?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ElementHandle`s those will be variables linking to the element found when the variable was created. This is one example you can try

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = 'hello';
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(span);
    });
  const el = await page.$('span');
  console.log(await el.innerText());
  await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('span').remove());
  await page.evaluate(() => {
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = 'world';
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(span);
  });
  console.log(await el.innerText());
  console.log(await page.innerText('span'));
  await browser.close();
})();
```

The output will be

```
hello
hello
world
```

Comment: Thanks @hardkoded. 
 I’ve written a fair about of UI test code with selenium, and easy to get a “Stale Ui Element exception” as the said libraries remove and add new DOM nodes whenever based on what they consider for perf.... 

I’m pretty new to playwright, and curious how playwright is expected to behave and when the UI Lib by delete and add nodes in the DOM?  Should one always assume to be safe always query for a new IElementHandle.  While the path would be the same, on the other hand, really impressed how fast playwright is :)

Comment: I honestly don't use many ElementHandles, not for the good or bad, but because the Page gives me all the tools for interacting with elements without picking the element in a variable.